xr.concat deforms my images when stacking tif file in nc file
I'm using this code to combine my tiff file into a .nc file :
import glob
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray as rxr
import pandas as pd

filenames = glob.glob('*.tif')
print(filenames)
transformed_filenames = [filename.replace("-", "") for filename in filenames]
print(transformed_filenames)
def time_index_from_filenames(filenames):
    '''helper function to create a pandas DatetimeIndex
       Filename example: 20150520_0164.tif'''
    return pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp(f[:8]) for f in filenames])


time = xr.Variable('time', time_index_from_filenames(transformed_filenames))
chunks = {'x': 1529, 'y': 2777, 'band': 1}
da = xr.concat([rxr.open_rasterio(f) for f in filenames], dim=time)

da = da.drop_vars('band') 
da.to_netcdf('OC3_AR.nc')

Eventhough this code worked well for one of my dataset it deforms my images for the second :
Tif file :
enter image description here
Nc file :
enter image description here
How to fix it ? Is it due to the projection (which is the same between the 2 images)? The dimensions are doubled on the nc file compared to the .tif (1529x2777 for tif vs 3058x5554)

It seems you are trying to perform xr.concat using files that have different lat/lon coordinates. Thats why your dimension values are getting doubled for the netcdf file, as well as this weird output result. I recommend you to check whether File 1 and File 2 share the same lat/lon values or not.

In case they do share the same lat/lon coordinates, it's possible that one of the files is getting flipped when converting from TIF to nc. GeoTIFF images often has a flipped display standard, so you might need to manually flip it: da.y = da.y[::-1] to match the original projection in both or one of the files.

In case they don't share the same lat/lon coordinates, you can try using xarray.Dataset.interp_like function to reproject File 1 lat/lon values according to File 2 coordinates.


